# #KeyPath to get variable or method name in Swift

Tags: swift

I am reading the documentation but cannot get something to work. I want to get the method or variable name in a class or struct. In Swift 3 you can apparently use #KeyPath. In Swift 4 it is easier. I cannot get either to work.

I want the string variable name to contain "Bar".

Here is my Playground code.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

class Foo {
    public var Bar:String {
        get {
            return "xxx"
        }
    }
}

var name = \Foo.Bar
print ("Member function name \(name) should be Bar")
```

In advance thank you for reading my question.

Comment: What is the benefit to get `Bar` by passing the actual name `...Bar` as parameter? The purpose of `#keyPath` is to be able to get the value `xxx` with key(path) subscription rather than dot notation even with nested subpaths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you want to get the name of a member at runtime?

Apparently, when you print a key path out, it does not print the name of the member. As an alternative, you can use a selector instead:

```
class Foo {
    // needs to be exposed to Obj-C
    @objc public var Bar:String {
        get {
            return "xxx"
        }
    }
}

var name = #selector(getter: Foo.Bar)
print ("Member function name \(name) should be Bar")
```

Prints:

> Member function name Bar should be Bar